# Some breakpoints not getting triggered

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm debugging a project and I noticed that only some of my breakpoints get triggered.

In my screenshot you can see I have 4 breakpoints. The first 2 get triggered when the program runs. I'm sure the code in the loginButtonPressed function gets called. I've proof of this printed on the console. The string "creating account" gets printed.

However! The last 2 breakpoints never get triggered. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If your project is running and after that you put breakpoint inside `loginButtonPressed` than you have to re run our project. if it doesn't work that quit Xcode and reopen it and run your project.

Comment: Tried those things. Didn't help

Comment: remove app, remove build cache, clean, rebuild